# Exception Handling in switch case - Android

Tags: java, android, exception, switch-statement

I have this piece of code, which is not working as expected :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_feedback: {
            try {
                Intent intent_email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent_email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"feedback@xyz.com"});
                intent_email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
                intent_email.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(intent_email);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Mail app found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        case R.id.action_rate: {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName())));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Market app found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem with this code is that when there's an Exception in `case R.id.action_rate:` it shows a Toast as **No Market app found** but when the Exception is in `case R.id.action_feedback:` it shows two Toasts, first **No Mail app found** & then **No Market app found**. Means it goes in both the catch blocks. Can anyone please explain how is it working like this ?

**However,** I have made my code working by putting the `try` block before `switch` statement and putting the catch block after the `switch` statement is closed. But still I don't know how the thing is going in this ?

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not breaking out of each case.
Try using a "break" after each case.

Comment: yes, but as I am using switch cases, and when I have clicked **Feedback**, then it shouldn't go the the next case which is **Rate**. So how it goes in the next catch block coz it is in other case.

Comment: if it throws an error in the first try statement, then it will go to the first catch block, after which it goes to the next case because a "break" is missing after the first catch

Answer (score 0):

You should always add `break;` in each case

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `break;` right after your first catch block. You may also need to rework your return statements.

Comment: Ok I agree that using break will solve the problem, but that's not my question. I asked how it goes to the next case even when I am not clicking that

Comment: Well, it goes to the next case **because** you did not have a break statement to prevent it from doing so.